# how to get value from CSSTEXT using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

```
var text = 'cssText: "@font-face { font-family: myFirstFont; src: url(http://fiddle.jshell.net/hiteshbhilai2010/dpfpLyq1/17/show/sansation_light.woff); }"';
```

how to get the `src: url(http://fiddle.jshell.net/myfiddle/dpfpLyq1/17/show/sansation_light.woff);` value from this.

I want to get source and fontFamily value and store it in my js variable. `fontSrc = url(http://fiddle.jshell.net/myfiddle/dpfpLyq1/17/show/sansation_light.woff)`

```
fontName = 'myFirstFont'
```

Can some one help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
var url = (text.match(/src: *url[^;]+;/i) || [""])[0];
//=> src: url(http://fiddle.jshell.net/hiteshbhilai2010/dpfpLyq1/17/show/sansation_light.woff);

var ff = (text.match(/font-family: *([^;]+);/i) || ["", ""])[1];
//=> myFirstFont
```

Comment: thanks it works just as I needed, one more help ...is it possible to get `font-family` as well

Comment: it says `undefined`... can u check pls ...http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/wpfskapr/1/

Comment: Sorry you need to use: `var name = (cssText.match(/font-family: *([^;]+);/i) || ["", ""])[1]` [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wpfskapr/6/)

Comment: but I still cant get `url(http://fiddle.jshell.net/myfiddle/dpfpLyq1/17/show/sansation_light.woff)` value ... it is `src : url(http://fiddle.jshell.net/myfiddle/dpfpLyq1/17/show/sansation_light.woff)` and it is not JSON ,I am having difficulty to get the value ...

Comment: can we change the regex to get the values

Comment: Sorry to bother you again and again ... but same thing does not work for `src` ..can you please see here http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/wpfskapr/9/ ... thanks